# etcdctl throws Error: context deadline exceeded error

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, coreos, etcd, etcd3

I'm trying to create a one node etcd cluster on AWS using coreos cloud-config. I have created a Route53 recordset with value `etcd.uday.com` which has a alias to the ELB which points to the ec2 instance. Etcd is running successfully but when I run the etcd member list command I get below error

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl member list \
--endpoints=https://etcd.udayvishwakarma.com:2379 \
--cacert=./ca.pem \
--cert=etcd-client.pem \
--key=etcd-client-key.pem

Error: context deadline exceeded
```

However, it lists members when `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` flag is added to the `etcdctl member list` command. I have generated certificated using `cfssl` using below configs

ca.json

```
{
"CN": "Root CA",
  "key": {
    "algo": "rsa",
    "size": 2048
  },
  "names": [
    {
      "C": "UK",
      "L": "London",
      "O": "Kubernetes",
      "OU": "CA"
    }
  ],
  "ca": {
    "expiry": "87658h"
  }
}
```

ca.config

```
 {
  "signing": {
    "default": {
      "expiry": "2190h"
    },
    "profiles": {
      "client": {
        "expiry": "8760h",
        "usages": [
          "signing",
          "key encipherment",
          "client auth"
        ]
      },
      "server": {
        "expiry": "8760h",
        "usages": [
          "signing",
          "key encipherment",
          "server auth"
        ]
      },
      "peer": {
        "expiry": "8760h",
        "usages": [
          "signing",
          "key encipherment",
          "server auth",
          "client auth"
        ]
      },
      "ca": {
        "usages": [
          "signing",
          "digital signature",
          "cert sign",
          "crl sign"
        ],
        "expiry": "26280h",
        "is_ca": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

etcd-member.json

```
 {
  "CN": "etcd",
  "key": {
    "algo": "rsa",
    "size": 2048
  },
  "hosts":[
    "etcd.uday.com"
  ],
  "names": [
    {
      "O": "Kubernetes"
    }
  ]
}
```

etcd-client.json

```
 {
  "CN": "etcd",
  "key": {
    "algo": "rsa",
    "size": 2048
  },
  "hosts":[
    "etcd.uday.com"
  ],
  "names": [
    {
      "O": "Kubernetes"
    }
  ]
}



     cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem -hostname="etcd.uday.com" \
          -config=ca-config.json -profile=peer \
etcd-member.json | cfssljson -bare etcd-member

    cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem -hostname="etcd.uday.com" \
    -config=ca-config.json -profile=client\
 etcd-client.json | cfssljson -bare etcd-client
```

My etcd-member.service systemd unit cloudconfig is as below

```
    units:
  - name: etcd-member.service
    drop-ins:
    - name: aws-etcd-cluster.conf
      content: |
        [Service]
        Environment=ETCD_USER=etcd
        Environment=ETCD_NAME=%H
        Environment=ETCD_IMAGE_TAG=v3.1.12
        Environment=ETCD_SSL_DIR=/etc/etcd/ssl

        Environment=ETCD_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
        Environment=ETCD_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/etcd-client.pem
        Environment=ETCD_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/etcd-client-key.pem
        Environment=ETCD_CLIENT_CERT_AUTH=true
        Environment=ETCD_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
        Environment=ETCD_PEER_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem
        Environment=ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/etcd-member.pem
        Environment=ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/etcd-member-key.pem
        Environment=ETCD_PEER_TRUSTED_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem


        Environment=ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE=new
        Environment=ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER=%H=https://%H:2380
        Environment=ETCD_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/etcd3
        Environment=ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS=https://%H:2379,https://127.0.0.1:2379
        Environment=ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=https://%H:2379
        Environment=ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS=https://%H:2380
        Environment=ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS=https://%H:2380
        PermissionsStartOnly=true
        Environment="RKT_RUN_ARGS=--uuid-file-save=/var/lib/coreos/etcd-member-wrapper.uuid"
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/rkt rm --uuid-file=/var/lib/coreos/etcd-member-wrapper.uuid
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sed -i 's/^ETCDCTL_ENDPOINT.*$/ETCDCTL_ENDPOINT=https:\/\/%H:2379/' /etc/environment
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/lib/etcd3
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown -R etcd:etcd /var/lib/etcd3
        ExecStop=-/usr/bin/rkt stop --uuid-file=/var/lib/coreos/etcd-member-wrapper.uuid
    enable: true
    command: start
```

Is cert generation wrong or something I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

The certificates are generated for `etcd.uday.com`.
You are trying to connect using `etcd.udayvishwakarma.com` while certificate is valid for `etcd.uday.com`.
Change endpoint on `etcdctl` from `etcd.udayvishwakarma.com` to `etcd.uday.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today, probably this is not going to be useful for you now, but it will for anybody who runs into the same problem in the future.
I think you might be missing

> etcd.udayvishwakarma.com

from your cert in

```
--cert=etcd-client.pem
```

To verify that etcd.udayvishwakarma.com exists in your cert, you can run:

```
openssl x509 -in etcd-client.pem -text
```

and you should be able to see it under X509v3 Subject Alternative Name. If you don't, you will probably need to recreate the certificate adding that DNS name.

Answer (score 0):

while i am  running `.\etcdctl.exe` put key value, i get this error

```
 Error: context deadline exceeded
```

befor running `etcdctl.exe` you should running `etcd.exe` first.
in my case it's working.